# Slim PHP Framework Session Length Make Longer

Tags: php, session, slim, session-timeout

I'm trying to figure out how to make sessions last longer in the SLIM PHP Framework.  **I'm aware of encrypted cookies and the cookie session feature**, but I can not use this because the data I'm storing in the session is greater than the amount of storage a cookie can hold.

Is there anyway to make sessions last longer?

I've tried the following code with no luck so far.  The session seems to last for about a couple of hours and then I have to re-login.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
    session_cache_limiter(false);
    session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's sessions are highly sensitive to your server's configuration.  There are many possible places where something could be going wrong:

### Server configuration

The server could be configured to prevent you from setting those particular configuration variables via `ini_set`.  If you don't have error-reporting turned on for warnings, you might not even know that these lines are failing.  You can use `phpinfo` to see the actual values in use during script execution.

### Debian/Ubuntu

Some operating systems like Debian and Ubuntu have their own garbage collector that periodically cleans up PHP sessions: https://serverfault.com/questions/511609/why-does-debian-clean-php-sessions-with-a-cron-job-instead-of-using-phps-built .

They don't care about your `gc_maxlifetime` setting; they just run on a fixed schedule.

### Shared hosting

Remember that PHP sessions are just stored as files on the server.  In (poorly configured) shared servers, it is common for all server accounts to write their sessions to the same directory by default.  In other words, there is nothing set up to distinguish which sessions belong to which server account.

Also, the value of `gc_maxlifetime` isn't associated with individual sessions in any way - it is a global value that gets set anew each time a script is invoked.  Combine that with the fact that PHP calls the session garbage collector when `session_start` is invoked, it is possible for some other account's script to delete your sessions according to whatever value of `gc_maxlifetime` they are using when invoked.

The only way to deal with this is by [placing your sessions in a separate directory](http://www.supernifty.org/blog/2008/04/19/php-sessions-on-shared-hosting-hack-3/).  Even then, you will need to make sure that `gc_maxlifetime` is set whenever one of your own scripts is invoked.  In general, this is a very good reason not to use PHP's native sessions if possible.  Packages like [Laravel's Session module](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#introduction) make it easy to deploy alternative session storage mechanisms, like memcache or database.